# How get query parameter in marionette controller

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

In early version Marionette we could use Marionette Controller

```
return Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        'admin/:controller/:action(?:query)': "controllerThird",
        '*notFound': "error"
    },
    controller: new Controller()
})

return Marionette.Controller.extend ({
    controllerThird: function (controller, action, query) {
        this.start(action);
    }
})
```

but now `Marionette.Controller`

> Warning: deprecated. The Controller object is deprecated. Instead of
>   using the Controller class with the AppRouter, you should specify your
>   callbacks on a plain Javascript object or a Marionette Object

We use MVC controller like

```
function (Backbone, Marionette, controller){

    "use strict";

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

        appRoutes: {

            "path1" : "goto_path1",
            "path2" : "goto_path2",
            "path3" : "goto_path3"
        }

    });

    return new AppRouter({controller: controller});

});

  define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'marionette',
  'app',
  'userSession'
], 
function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, App, userSession) {

    return {
        goto_path1: function () {
                //I need get current query in this point 

        },
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application

In Controller handler I want access to  action, query params  like

```
controllerThird: function (controller, action, query)
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually keep most of your existing code and it will still work. It's as simple as what the deprecation message suggests.

Simply replace the Controller

```
return Marionette.Controller.extend ({
    controllerThird: function (controller, action, query) {
      this.start(action);
    }
})
```

With a Marionette Object:

```
return Marionette.Object.extend ({
    controllerThird: function (controller, action, query) {
      this.start(action);
    }
})
```

See here for a more extensive example

https://marionette.gitbooks.io/marionette-guides/content/en/appendix/approuter/router.html#router-and-controller